# Color every nth row

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I would like to color every nth row in a Google Sheets and tried different formulae like:

```
mod((row(A5:A10)-row($A$5)+1),3)=0
```

(found this info [here](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/highlight-every-nth-row-or-column-in-google-sheets/)) but, it didn't work.

I also tried playing around with the formula, with no success.

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: May give this formula found here a shot (https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm00jJdEt-y8kk/?hl=en). If that doesn't work, maybe look into Conditional Formatting.

Comment: @TimothyBomer I tried that too, didnt work :(

Answer (score 1):

The MOD() based formula you've been given should work, see the screenshot below to see if you're doing the same thing:

[image]